# Как можно придать определенный стиль вертикальному скроллу?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Добрый вечер!

Подскажите, как можно придать определенный стиль вертикальному скроллу (overflow-y: scroll), отличному от изначального?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/#examples

http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/

https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/ (это не кроссбраузерный вариант)

на русском http://htmlbook.ru/blog/polzovatelskie-skrollbary-v-webkit

Answer (score 0):

Например, для вебкит-браузеров. Учитывайте ширину этого скролла при разработке с использованием медиа-запросов.

```
 ::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 12px; }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track { -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); border-radius: 10px; }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background: @c-sea; border-radius: 10px; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
```